# Finding and Reducing Journal Disk Usage

Tags: disk-usage, systemd-journald, bleachbit

In Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, I ran Disk Usage Analyzer on the root directory. It indicated that /var/log/journal occupied 3.8GB. In response, I ran `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/journald.conf` and changed two lines: `25 SystemMaxUse=100M` and `33 MaxRetentionSec=1week`. Then I ran `sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald`. I rebooted and refreshed Disk Usage Analyzer. The situation remained the same. It appeared that my efforts accomplished nothing.

I didn't run `journalctl --disk-usage` before those edits to `journald.conf`. I did run it afterwards. It said, "Archived and active journals take up 64.0M in the file system." Possibly my changes to `journald.conf` contributed to that relatively low value of 64.0M. In any event, that 64.0M figure seemed incompatible with the results of Disk Usage Analyzer.

Were Disk Usage Analyzer and `journalctl --disk-usage` providing information on different aspects of the system? Was Disk Usage Analyzer identifying a large amount of material that I could have reduced, so as to make more space on the drive?

I used BleachBit before taking any of these steps: was it perhaps the reason for the relatively low space usage indicated by `journalctl --disk-usage`? I included most BleachBit options, excepting only those whose warnings mentioned instability or went beyond "slow" to "very slow" - for instance, I didn't use its option to clean free disk space.

Comment: In BleachBit did you use the tool to clean free disk space? This is the one that can take hours.